# [HELP!]Has indigo vmware or virtual-box image file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know ROS Hydro Medusa has a pre-installed virtual machine file with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS .
This link said: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation
*Alternatively, you can use a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and ROS Hydro Medusa pre-installed. It is packaged in an .ova file of approx. 3.7GB that you can run on VirtualBox or other virtualization engines.*

ROS indigo has this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194100/%5Bhelp!%5Dhas-indigo-vmware-or-virtual-box-image-file-?/) by [roschina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20157/roschina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roschina](https://answers.ros.org/users/20157/roschina/) on 2014-10-03**:
Oh yes ! in the below. I saw .
Thanks